# submit_tag with check_box_tag returning error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having some trouble with `check_box_tag` and my method *enable* (a product can be disabled) in Ruby on Rails.
I created some checkbox so the user select the products that he wants to set enable = true.
Keeps returning the error "Couldn't find Product with 'id'=enable"

My method `enable`:

```
def enable
   Product.update_all(["enable=?", true], :id => params[:selected_products])
   redirect_to root_url
end
```

My `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'product_export/new'

  get 'product_imports/new'

  resources :users
  resources :product_imports
  resources :products do
    collection do
      post :import
      post :export
      post :enable
    end
  end

  root to: 'products#index'
end
```

and finally my `view` with the table e the check_box_tag:

```
<%= form_tag enable_products_path, :method => :put do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Enable products" %>
  <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" id="productsTable">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th/>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Enable</th>
        <th>Bar code</th>
        <th>Unit cost</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Family</th>
        <th>Final</th>
        <th>Measure</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= check_box_tag 'selected_products[]', product.id %></td>
          <td><%= link_to (product.code), edit_product_path(product) %></td>
          <td><%= product.enable %></td>
          <td><%= product.bar_code %></td>
          <td><%= product.unit_cost %></td>
          <td><%= product.description %></td>
          <td><%= product.family %></td>
          <td><%= product.final %></td>
          <td><%= product.measure %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: check what url is hitting in console. I think it is  products/enable right?

Comment: Show a part of your rails log (log/development.log) for this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `where` to find selected products and when to update them:

`Product.where(id: params[:selected_products]).update_all(enable: true)`